# Applying a correct logic after successful validation in Symfony

Tags: symfony

First of I all, I created the whole example below specifically for this question because the actual example is very big so if it looks stupid then assume that it is not for now!

I'm trying to come up with a solution so that I can call a correct private method (`bankA()` or `bankB()`) in controller if the validation successfully passes. As you can see in the custom validation constraint, I only check the `$bank->code` property however the condition is not actually that simple (there is repository checks so on) - (as I said above, it is trimmed down version). So, could please someone tell me, how will I know that which private method I should call in controller after successful validation? I'm happy to create dedicated validators if necessary so open for suggestions and examples.

**Note:** I looked into symfony group validation documentation but didn't really get the picture how I could apply to my scenario.

**EXAMPLE REQUEST**

- `{ "id": 66, "code": "A" }`
- `{ "id": 34, "code": "B" }`

**CONTROLLER**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

/**
 * @Route("bank", service="application_frontend.controller.bank")
 */
class BankController extends Controller
{
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(
        ValidatorInterface $validator
    ) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @Route("")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $content = $request->getContent();
        $content = json_decode($content, true);

        $bank = new Bank();
        $bank->id = $content['id'];
        $bank->code = $content['code'];

        $errors = $this->validator->validate($bank);
        if (count($errors)) {
            throw new Exception($errors[0]->getMessage());
        }

        // OK, validation has passed so which one do I call now ?!?!
        $this->bankA($bank);
        $this->bankB($bank);
    }

    private function bankA(Bank $bank)
    {
        // Do something nice with Bank
    }

    private function bankB(Bank $bank)
    {
        // Do something bad with Bank
    }
}
```

**BANK MODEL**

```
use Application\FrontendBundle\Validator\Constraint as BankAssert;

/**
 * @BankAssert\Bank
 */
class Bank
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $code;
}
```

**CUSTOM VALIDATOR**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Bank extends Constraint
{
    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }
}

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class BankValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($bank, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($bank->code == 'A') {
            return;
        }

        if ($bank->code == 'B') {
            return;
        }

        $this->context->buildViolation('Bank error')->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the logic behind? you would call bankA if code is A and bankB if code is B? is this right?

Comment: But A and B is just demonstration purposes so I'm not just checking if it is A or B in validation. There are more checks to `$bank->code` against repository and some other services.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many codes there are you could either do...

```
if ('A' === $bank->getCode()) {
    $this->bankA($bank);
} else {
    $this->bankB($bank);
}
```

Or..

```
$method = 'bank'.$bank->getCode();

if (!method_exists($this, $method)) {
    throw new \Exception('Method "'.$method.'" does not exist');
}

$this->$method();
```

All of that being said, it would be advisable to move all of this work into a dedicated service rather than in your controller. Then in your controller use something like...

```
$this->container->get('do_something_to_bank.service')->processAction($bank);
```

Comment: `$bank->code` can be anything. I just used A and B in the method names and the request payload to simplify the code but obviously I caused misunderstanding and I can only blame myself for it. Anyway, the whole aim is to know which method is to be called after validation. If X validation rule is applied then `bankA()`, if Y validation is used then `bankB()` will be called in controller. Also I actually use models, factories and services for specific logic so I don't really use controller to do all that code you see above. I just wanted to keep it as tidy as possible for the readers.

Comment: Fair enough. Without actual code I'm finding it hard to conceptualise the actual problem. Sorry.

Comment: OK, lets say this then. You want to validate `$bank` model twice. Once against `BankStepOneValidator` and then `BankStepTwoValidator `. Is this possible? Another option: can I pass some kind of variable/param to validator so that `BankValidator` above know which if statement is to be run?

Comment: If you just want to do Step1 then Step 2 you can use groups and group sequences. If you only want to validate if it fits certain criteria then I suppose you could set a flag in your object in the first validator. I'm still not sure what you're after though, to be honest.